# c get the next char without space

Tags: c

I need  help with below code. Program does a simple arithmetic calculations. The problem is 2(space)+3 works fine, but 2+3 doesn't read the operator. How can I make it work without space?
getchar and putchar are must, no string functions. The program is to extract the 2 operanads and the operator, perform indicated calculation and display the result. Thanks in advance.

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)  /*Begining of the while loop*/
{
    if ((status == first)) {  
        if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9'))
        {
            num1 = ((num1 * 10) + (ch - '0'));
        }
        else status = operand;
    }
    else if (status == operand)
    {
        if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/' || ch == '%'){
            /*count++;*/
            oper = ch;
            /*printf("Count %d \n", count);
        }
        else if (count>1){  // This opening brace was missing
            printf("Operator Error.\n");*/
            status = second;
        }
    }
    else if ((status == second) && ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9'))){
        num2 = ((num2 * 10) + (ch - '0'));
    }
}
```

Comment: the code is not complete so it is difficult to help because it makes us guess e.g. num1 and num2 what are they initially? generally speaking i think it would clearer if you had a switch statement with status

Comment: I tried editing your code and noticed, that there supposedly is a closing brace missing in line `else if (count>1)`. I'm pretty sure that you will get help here, if you edit your code so that it is a complete program with only the problem-part present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This omits the status variable and checks to see if operand has been assigned to determine if the digits are used for num1 or num2. Non-digits are consumed in the else and if they are a valid operand, operand is assigned. Input stops on EOF or '\n'

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int ch = 0;
    char operand = 0;

    while (((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && ch != '\n') {
        if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9')) { // digits
            if (operand == 0) {
                num1 = ((num1 * 10) + (ch - '0')); // no operand so use num1
            }
            else {
                num2 = ((num2 * 10) + (ch - '0')); // operand has been assigned
            }
        }
        else { // non digits
            if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/' || ch == '%'){
                if ( operand == 0) { // do not re-assign operand
                    operand = ch; // assign operand
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf ( "num1 %d operand %c num2 %d\n", num1, operand, num2);
    return 0;
}
```

This might also work instead of the while loop above
%d reads an integer
%1[-+/*%] reads a single character that must be one of the valid operands. the space before the %1 skips any whitespace if present
%d reads another integer
If scanf successfully reads the three values, they are printed.

```
char operand[2] = {0};
if ( ( scanf ( "%d %1[-+/*%] %d", &num1, operand, &num2)) == 3) {
    printf ( "num1 %d operand %c num2 %d\n", num1, operand[0], num2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF){
    if ((status == first)) {  
        if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9')) {
            num1 = ((num1 * 10) + (ch - '0'));
        } else
            status = operand;//already read one char. or use ungetc  E.g.{ status = operand; ungetc(ch, stdin); }
    }
    if (status == operand) {
        if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/' || ch == '%'){
            oper = ch;
            status = second;
        }
    } else if ((status == second) && ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9'))){
        num2 = ((num2 * 10) + (ch - '0'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. But what with eating whitespaces between tokens ?

Comment: @soerium Space is simply ignored in the respective conditions.

Comment: Right, but if the very first chars are whitespaces your implementation will not handle it in respective conditions and in result switch to next token (operand).

Comment: @soerium Not allowed to space before num1 that it is the original specification. There is no phase transition to the state of the `first` in the implementation of the OP.

Comment: If the original specification says so, then mea culpa.

Comment: I suspect it is not my job.